# Get semantic model from a classifier VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, roslyn

As R# is not supporting the Roslyn Early Preview C# 6.0 features, the code looks very dull...

I would like to colorize the code using a classifier VSIX. Is it possible to get the semantic model from the Roslyn Language Service for the current document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a reference to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text.dll, then use the following code.

```
var doc = point.Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
var model = await doc.GetSemanticModelAsync();
```

This requires the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text` NuGet package (.NET 4.6 required)

Comment: Unfortunately, point.Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges() returns always null

Comment: @Liviu: What kind of document is it? What's the `ContentType` of the `TextBuffer`? Is the Roslyn preview installed in the VS hive you're running in? (with matching version)

Comment: I've eventually figured out that debug session was running in Exp hive.

Comment: @Liviu: Note that you can install the Roslyn preview to a different hive, and you can also change which hive your addin builds to.

Comment: GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges is giving me some weird accessibility issues.

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein install the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text package, which changes the accessibility of this method by adding an extension method with that name