# Get current source file methods in Visual Studio Text Editor Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I try to write extension for Visual Studio, but I can't find documentation about my question. In SDK examples only for some things like text hightliting, but no any example which demostrate how directly work with Intelliscense. Documentations from MSDN - also not good.
It is possible - get list of all methods from current opened source file, if I have IWpfTextView?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869722/get-semantic-model-from-a-classifier-vsix and https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#CreateTypedVariable

Comment: If I will use Rolsyn, I will might get methods only for C# and VBasic, right?

Comment: Yes, Roslyn supports only C# and VB.

Comment: But I need it for C/C++, sorry that haven't told about this in topic at first. I just thought that  I could get list of methods from Intellisense for all languages, which Intellisense knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is possible - get list of all methods from current opened source file, if I have IWpfTextView?

You can get list of all methods via CodeElement and check if it a CodeFunction object. The following code for your reference.

You can get current opened source file via DTE.ActiveDocument

```
DTE2 dte = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
            FileCodeModel fcm = dte.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel as FileCodeModel;
            foreach (CodeElement element in fcm.CodeElements)
            {
                if (element is CodeNamespace)
                {
                    CodeNamespace nsp = element as CodeNamespace;

                    foreach (CodeElement subElement in nsp.Children)
                    {
                        if (subElement is CodeClass)
                        {
                            CodeClass c2 = subElement as CodeClass;
                            foreach (CodeElement item in c2.Children)
                            {
                                if (item is CodeFunction)
                                {
                                    CodeFunction cf = item as CodeFunction;
                                    MessageBox.Show(cf.Name);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Oh,Thanks a lot! But as i understand for this method the file must be in project, alse we will have null instead FileCodeModel object? I tried to google how I also can get FileCodeMode for file without getting ProjectItem (just if I create\open new file not in project), but I don't found it. And because that I asked how get list of methods from Intelliscense, because I think that that it will possible for any file. Maybe You know how get list of methods, if file not in project? :)

Comment: as Sergey Aksenov mentioned before, you could use Roslyn to achieve it.

Comment: as I answered before, Roslyn can't solve my problem, because I needed to get methods for C/C++ files

Comment: So, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za2b25t3.aspx) possible to see that what I want is impossible in current object model. It's sad, but getting CodeMode from ProjectItems - is better, than nothing. Thanks!